# Is there a function whose derivative is proportional to that function squared?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a Physics problem. The problem involves a ball of mass m falling through the air, with the drag force at a time t being equal to $bv^3(t)$. The problem wants me to find and solve a differential equation for the instantaneous velocity at a given time. I did some research, and I found an article on the Oregon State University website which explains how to solve the equation assuming that drag is directly proportional to velocity. I tried solving it the same way, and I eventually end up at a point where an auxiliary function $p'(t) = -2\frac{b^2}{m^2}p^2(t)$. This is pretty much where the problem dead-ended for me, though.

My two questions are:

1) Is there an elementary function / combination of elementary functions such that $f'(t)\propto f^2(t)$?

2) How do I actually solve this equation for $v(t)$?

Comment: you get this $$\frac 1 p=2\frac {b^2}{m^2}t+K$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*1) Is there an elementary function / combination of elementary functions such that $f′(t)∝f^2(t)$  ?*

Yes. Take for example $f(x)=1/x$ we have $f'(x)=-\frac 1 {x^2}$ and also $f^2(x)=\frac 1 {x^2}$
$$p'(t) = -2\frac{b^2}{m^2}p^2(t)$$
This differential equation is separable. If you solve the equation in p you get :
$$\int \frac {dp}{p^2}= -2\int \frac{b^2}{m^2}dt$$

$$\frac 1 p=2\frac {b^2}{m^2}t+K$$
Invert fractions on both sides you get
$$ p(t)=\frac 1{ {2\frac {b^2}{m^2}t+K}}$$
multiply denominator and numerator by $m^2$
$$ p(t)=\frac {m^2} { {2 {b^2}t+Km^2}}$$
Substitute $C=m^2K$ which is just a constant

$$\implies p(t)=\frac {m^2} {2{b^2}t+C}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I was wondering if you could explain your last step, though? I don't understand how you get that m^2 into the numerator.

Comment: @NullSpark just elementary fractions nothing to do with differential calculus ..I will add some lines

Comment: @NullSpark is it more clear now ?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome @NullSpark

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as it was nonsense.

Comment: no problem John really @badjohn

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that I would tidy up in case it confused anyone else.